# I am trying to insert multiple rows using postgres and php

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am attempting to insert these array values using a foreach loop and keep getting the errors `Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","` and `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function pg_execute() on bool`. Have I missed something here in regard to a prepared statement. I am new to postgres and this seems like it should work. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=dev password=password");

if (!$conn) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}
    
$rows = array (
            array(
                "3",
                null,
                "1",
                "accountmanager",
                "acountmanager@email.com",
                "asdfasdfasdf",
                "Role",
                "f",
                "Developer",
                "accountmanager@email.com",
                null,
                null,
                "America/New_York",
                null,
                null,
                "active",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ),
            array (
                "4",
                null,
                "1",
                "superdeveloper",
                "superdeveloper@email.com",
                "$2a$12$sdfs/d",
                "Role",
                "f",
                "Guy",
                "superdevr@email.com",
                null,
                null,
                "America/New_York",
                null,
                null,
                "active",
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            )
        );

$args = array_fill(0, count($rows[0]), '?');

$query = "INSERT INTO   public.users(id,ext_id,container_id,first_name,username,password,last_name,is_supervisor,title,email,phone,mobile,timezone,suffix,timestamp,status,user_custom_values_json,transient_json,api_key,api_secret,third_party_auth_type,third_party_auth_json) VALUES (".implode(',', $args).")";

$stmt = pg_prepare($conn, "myquery", $query);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $stmt->pg_execute($row);
}

?>
```

When I var_dump $query I get `string(314) "INSERT INTO public.users(id,ext_id,container_id,first_name,username,password,last_name,is_supervisor,title,email,phone,mobile,timezone,suffix,timestamp,status,user_custom_values_json,transient_json,api_key,api_secret,third_party_auth_type,third_party_auth_json) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"`  I am having trouble getting the array values from ```$rows``into the query.

Comment: Please update your question if the original question is no longer your issue.

Comment: Also show the complete formatted result of ```$query = "INSERT INTO ...```.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this ```INSERT INTO public.users(id,ext_id,container_id,first_name,username,password,last_name,is_supervisor,title,email,phone,mobile,timezone,suffix,timestamp,status,user_custom_values_json,transient_json,api_key,api_secret,third_party_auth_type,third_party_auth_json) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php

Comment: @Luuk Thank you that did the trick